# Issues finding common bi grams in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to apply a query to search down one column (Text) of a table, and to return the most common bi-grams within it.

I came across this query but I'm struggling to manipulate it to fit my dataset:

```
SELECT word, nextword, COUNT(*) c 
FROM (
SELECT pos, title, word, LEAD(word) OVER(PARTITION BY created_utc,title ORDER BY pos) nextword FROM (
SELECT created_utc, title, word, pos FROM FLATTEN(
  (SELECT created_utc, title, word, POSITION(word) pos FROM
   (SELECT created_utc, title, SPLIT(title, ' ') word FROM [bigquery-samples:reddit.full])
  ), word)
))
WHERE nextword IS NOT null
GROUP EACH BY 1, 2
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 100
```

(The query was orginally written for the Reddit comments dump)

How do I change this query to look down my 'Text' column and nothing else?

I'm a little cofused as to what 'pos' and 'title' refer to - please be patient, I'm new to SQL! :)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: which text column are you referring to - Title? Title and pos refer to title field and SPLIT(title, ' ') word from [bigquery-samples:reddit.full] table. Split(title, ' ') will split the title using space (' ') and separate out the word.